# Express $\frac{\ln\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}{80000000}$ as a negative exponent

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I would like to express $\dfrac{\ln\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}{80000000}$ as a negative exponent. Using [Desmos online calculator](https://www.desmos.com/calculator) I tried this variant:

[image]

Why are the results different? I expected/goal was to be the same result.

How can I express $\dfrac{\ln\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}{80000000}$ not as a fraction?

Comment: Some of this may just be an input-to-the-calculator thing. It's cleaner with letters. (ln(b))/c = (1/c) ln(b) = ln(b^(1/c)) and it's just a question of keeping track of parentheses when b or c are themselves fractions.

Comment: In the second, it is probably taking the log of $\frac 12$, which is negative, and refusing to raise it to a non-integer power.  You need another set of parentheses to indicate it should be the power before the log.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

\begin{align}
\frac{\ln(\frac12)}{8\cdot 10^7}
&=
\frac{1}{8\cdot 10^7}\cdot \ln(\frac12)\\
&=
\frac{1}8{\cdot 10^{-7}}\cdot \ln(\frac12)\\
&=\ln\left((\frac12)^{\frac{1}8{\cdot 10^{-7}}}\right)\\
&\ne\ln\left((\frac12)^{-8{\cdot 10^{7}}}\right)
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

$$a\ln b=\ln\left(b^a\right)$$

Using this fact, we can write

$$\frac{\ln\left(\frac12\right)}{80000000}=\frac1{80000000}\ln\left(\frac12\right)=\ln\left(\left(\frac12\right)^{\frac1{80000000}}\right)=\ln\left(\frac{1^{\frac1{80000000}}}{2^{\frac1{80000000}}}\right)=\ln\left(2^{-\frac1{80000000}}\right)$$